# React won't render page when loading from CDN

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Can't seem to render a page with React using the CDN links.

My index.html file looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
      
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="index.js" type="text/babel"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my index.js only contains:

```
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello</h1>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Can't figure out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: React 18 has a different process. [I would start here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html) to rule out any issues with that first.

Answer (score 1):

You are using ReactDOM.render() in your React 18, you will see the below warning.

**Warning:** ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead.

The **reason** is ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18.

If we are using React 18, we should start using createRoot() instead of render().

**Example:**

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<h1>Hello</h1>);
```

In your file *index.js*, change to:

```
const container = document.getElementById("root");
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);
root.render(<h1>Hello</h1>);
```